# Office 365 MFA with Azure SQL Database MFA

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

An Azure SQL database is set to allow login for `X` security group(active directory admin), this same security group is having Office 365 MFA enabled. Now when ever `X` group user login to Azure SQL database using MFA they are only asked `password` not the second authentication(Code via phone, code on Microsoft authentication app or call on phone) but its not the same when these users login to Azure, teams etc where they are asked to authenticate 2nd time also. What is the reason behind this ?

Answer (score 0):

So after R&D i figured out it was because of **Trusted location** which will not ask for 2nd authentication and if the user login from outside the Trusted location they will be asked for 2nd authentication.